# How to Convert and Reverse MAC Address to Bytes C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, serial-port, hex

I need to convert an MAc Address - 88:E9:FE:A8:1F:2F
for this format '0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000'

I did this code below, but it is not elegant. Someone can help me?

```
        string txtMacAddr =  "88:E9:FE:A8:1F:2F";
        string cmdMAc = "";

        var macReverso = Util.Mac_Reverso(txtMacAddr.Replace(":",""));
        string[] macRev = new string[4];

        macRev[0] = $"0x{macReverso.Substring(4, 8)}";
        macRev[1] = $"0x0000{macReverso.Substring(0, 4)}";
        macRev[2] = "0x00000000";
        macRev[3] = "0x00000000";

        foreach (var xl in macRev)
        {
            cmdMAc += xl + " ";
            
        }

        Logger.WriteLine(cmdMAc); //op '0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000'


        public static string Mac_Reverso(string macAddress)
        {
          string macRevertido = string.Empty; 
          string s = macAddress.Replace("0x", "");//'0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000'
          string[] macLista = s.Split(' ');

          foreach (var mac in macLista)
          {
            for (var i = mac.Length; i > 0; i -= 2)
            {
                macRevertido += mac.Substring(i - 2, 2);
                if (macRevertido.Length == 12)
                {
                    
                    return macRevertido; //2F1FA8FEE988
                }
            }                               
          }

          return macRevertido;
       }
```

Comment: A MAC address is not a 'number'.  It's an array of 6 bytes in order.  You appear to be trying to make it into some kind of int (0x...), which it just isn't. Also, trying to make it a 'number' will you probably bump into endian issues, especially, as you appear to be doing, moving between platforms.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by not elegant? The following code will get the same result and in my opinion its easier to read. The first option is to show it can be done just by using char references, if the mac address will always look the same. The second result is easier to read in my head.

Note: If 88 was changed to 08 and the zero was omitted for some reason, the the following input would break both of them: `8:E9:FE:A8:1F:2F` Does this case matter to you?

Is the output you included in your post what you are trying to get? What exactly are you trying to do?

```
    //Reference each char individually. Could break if char position changes.
    string mac =  "88:E9:FE:A8:1F:2F";
    string reverseMac = "0x" + mac[9] + mac[10] + mac[6] + mac[7] + mac[3] + mac[4] + mac[0] + mac[1] + " 0x0000" + mac[15] + mac[16] + mac[12] + mac[13] + " 0x00000000 0x00000000";   
    //Output:0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000
    
    //Better Option: Split by the ':' delimiter and reference each group of chars. 
    string[] macChars = mac.Split(":"); //Breaks into groups
    string newMac2 = "0x" + macChars[3] + macChars[2] + macChars[1] + macChars[0] + " 0x0000" + macChars[5] + macChars[4] + " 0x00000000 0x00000000";
    //Output: 0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000
```

**Update:** Based on what you are trying to do, two methods would be better. You could reuse your Mac_Reverso in place of RevertMac below.

```
    //Input 88:E9:FE:A8:1F:2F
    //Output 0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000
    public static string ConvertMac(string macAddress)
    {
        string[] macChars = macAddress.Split(":");
        string macRevertido = "0x" + macChars[3] + macChars[2] + macChars[1] + macChars[0] + " 0x0000" + macChars[5] + macChars[4] + " 0x00000000 0x00000000";

        return macRevertido;
    }

    //Input  0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000
    //Output 88:E9:FE:A8:1F:2F
    public static string RevertMac(string mc)
    { 
        string revertedMac = "" + mc[8] + mc[9] + ":" + mc[6] + mc[7] + ":"  + mc[4] + mc[5] + ":"  + mc[2] + mc[3] + ":"  + mc[19] + mc[20] + ":"  + mc[17] + mc[18];
        return revertedMac;
    }
```

This doesn't address the endian issues Neil mentioned. Your question mentions reversing bytes, and your output format implies reversing the *order* of bytes in the array. Is that your objective?

Comment: First I need to convert this string -'0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000'  to MAC Address (6 bits 88: E9: FE: A8: 1F: 2F) and show it to the system user. It will edit the MAC Address and I need to convert the new MAC Address to this format again '0xA8FEE988 0x00002F1F 0x00000000 0x00000000' (it will be sent via serial to device).  i am using this function for invert  string   Mac_Reverso(string macAddress)